# How-to go parallel

Tags: r

I have a dataset as below:

```
Custid    Product
 12         A
 12         B
 12         C
 13         A
 13         B
 13         D
 14         B
 14         D
 14         E
 15         A
 15         E
 15         B
 16         C
 16         A
 16         D
```

So I have 5 distinct products (A B C D E) for customers (each getting 3). Now I want 5 text files for each product with the custids in them. for example:
test file for A should have custids-

```
12 
13 
15 
16
```

and similarly other products should have text files with their custids that are asigned those products.

Is there a way to do it via parallel processing in R as I have millions of records with such data?

Comment: i would suggest to go through [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/),then if still unclear ask again

Answer (score 0):

```
by(dat,dat$Product,function(x)write.csv(x,paste0(x[1,2],".txt")))
```

Now go to your working directory and check for the existence of these files. or try reading from your console: `read.csv("A.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

To do it in a parallel way use the package `parallel`.

```
library(parallel)
lst=split(x = df,f = df$Product)
mcmapply(function(t,n){write(t$Custid,paste0(n,".txt"),ncolumns = 1,append = TRUE)},lst,names(lst),mc.preschedule=TRUE)
```